Limit of complex function with $\frac{-\infty}{0}$ form
How would I go about computing $\lim_{z\to i} \frac{\ln(z^2 + 1)}{z^2 + 1}$? I can't apply L'Hôpital's rule as the fraction is of the form $\frac{-\infty}{0}$ and don't really have any other ideas as to how to approach this.

Well, $\infty/0$ is certainly $\infty$, if that is the problem.

@Conrad $z \to i$

sorry you are right limit is infinity

The limit does not exist; do you need to say anything more than that? Note that limits in the complex plane are, well, complex; even the assertion "$\lim_{z\to i} \ln(z^2+1) = -\infty$" implied by the title isn't really correct, since $\ln(z^2+1)$ will have lots of different imaginary parts for $z$ close to $i$.
